# How to add home directory path to be discovered by Unix which command?

Tags: path, profile, home, which

I have installed `node.js` at custom location and added the location to the `$PATH` in `.profile` file.

```
$ node --version
v0.6.2
$ which node
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:~/Unix/homebrew/bin
$ cat ~/.profile
export  PATH="$PATH:~/Unix/homebrew/bin"
```

Node.js itself runs well. The problem is it is not listed by `which` command. So I can't install `npm` now. Because `npm` install cannot find the location of `node.js`. How can I make the `node` binary discovered by `which`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because `~` has not been expanded. Your shell knows how to deal with this, but `which` does not (nor would most other programs). Instead, do:

```
export "PATH+=:$HOME/Unix/homebrew/bin"
```

Alternatively, stop using `which`, and use the (almost always superior) `type -p`.

Here is a demonstration of the issue:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ export "PATH+=:~/git/yturl"
$ yturl
Usage: yturl id [itag ...]
$ which yturl
$ type -p yturl
/home/chris/git/yturl/yturl
$ export "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$HOME/git/yturl"
$ which yturl
/home/chris/git/yturl/yturl
```

Bear in mind that some other programs that look at `$PATH` may not understand the meaning of `~` either, and take it as part of a relative path. It's more portable to use `$HOME`.

Comment: While the proposed solution does work, the explanation is wrong. `which` is not at fault here; the `~` should have been expanded in the definition of `PATH`. There's an oddity in bash that it expands the `~` anyway in `PATH`, so two wrongs make a right, kind of.

Comment: @Gilles How does that differ from what I said?

Comment: The fact that this works at all with the quoted `~` is a bash oddity. Having that literal `~` in `$PATH` is likely to cause trouble down the line because there are programs that do their own splitting of `$PATH` and they don't treat `~` specially.

Comment: @Gilles ...and how does that differ from what I said in my final paragraph?

Comment: While it's technically true that “some other program … may not understand the meaning of `~`”, your sentence is misleading. In the context of `$PATH`, this is every program other than bash.

Comment: Where as `type -p` may be superior, `which` is far easier to remember for a command that you type once every few months.

Answer (score 19):

That line in your `.profile` should be one of

```
export  PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Unix/homebrew/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Unix/homebrew/bin"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Unix/homebrew/bin
PATH=$PATH:~/Unix/homebrew/bin
```

The `~` character is only expanded to your home directory when it's the first character of a word and it's unquoted. In what you wrote, the `~` is between double quotes and therefore not expanded. Even if you wrote `export "PATH=$PATH:"~/Unix/homebrew/bin`, the `~` would not be expanded because it is not at the beginning of a shell word.

There is a special dispensation, which is intended to write values for `PATH` and similar variables. If `~` is just after the equal sign that marks an assignment, or if `~` is just after a `:` in the right-hand side of an assignment, then it's expanded. Only plain assignments have this dispensation, `export PATH=…` does not count (it's a call to the `export` builtin, which happens to have an argument that contains a `=` character).

Here, you do not need to export `PATH` because it's already exported. You don't need to call `export` when you change the value of a variable (except in old Bourne shells that you won't find on OSX or Linux). Also, in an assignment (again, `export` does not count), you do not need double quotes around the right-hand side, so `PATH=$PATH:~/Unix/homebrew/bin` is safe even if `$PATH` contains spaces.