# How to correctly add a path to PATH?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path, bashrc

I'm wondering where a new path has to be added to the `PATH` environment variable. I know this can be accomplished by editing `.bashrc` (for example), but it's not clear how to do this.

This way:

```bsh
export PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH
```

or this?

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin
```

Comment: printf '\nPATH=$PATH:"path-to-add"\nexport PATH\n' >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: [Unix shell function for adding directories to PATH](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/88236/70616)

Comment: If there are already some paths added, e.g. `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin`, another can be added by separating with a : e.g. `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/home/ec2-user/pear/bin`.

Comment: Do these answers work for all flavors of linux?

Comment: Related: [Add directory to $PATH if it's not already there](https://superuser.com/q/39751/150988) (on [SU]).

Comment: wrote a little utility to help with exactly this. https://github.com/aalok-sathe/pathin

Answer (score 1534, accepted):

#### The simple stuff

```
PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin
```

or

```
PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH
```

depending on whether you want to add `~/opt/bin` at the end (to be searched after all other directories, in case there is a program by the same name in multiple directories) or at the beginning (to be searched before all other directories).

You can add multiple entries at the same time. `PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin:~/opt/node/bin` or variations on the ordering work just fine. Don't put `export` at the beginning of the line as it has additional complications (see below under “Notes on shells other than bash”).

If your `PATH` gets built by many different components, you might end up with duplicate entries. See [How to add home directory path to be discovered by Unix which command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25605/how-to-add-home-directory-path-to-be-discovered-by-unix-which-command) and [Remove duplicate $PATH entries with awk command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40749/remove-duplicate-path-entries-with-awk-command) to avoid adding duplicates or remove them.

Some distributions automatically put `~/bin` in your PATH if it exists, by the way.

#### Where to put it

Put the line to modify `PATH` in `~/.profile`, or in `~/.bash_profile` or if that's what you have. (If your login shell is zsh and not bash, put it in `~/.zprofile` instead.)

The profile file is read by login shells, so it will only take effect the next time you log in. (Some systems configure terminals to read a login shell; in that case you can start a new terminal window, but the setting will take effect only for programs started via a terminal, and how to set `PATH` for all programs depends on the system.)

Note that `~/.bash_rc` is not read by any program, and `~/.bashrc` is the configuration file of interactive instances of bash. You should not define environment variables in `~/.bashrc`. The right place to define environment variables such as `PATH` is `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` if you don't care about shells other than bash). See [What's the difference between them and which one should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980)

Don't put it in `/etc/environment` or `~/.pam_environment`: these are not shell files, you can't use substitutions like `$PATH` in there. In these files, you can only override a variable, not add to it.

#### Potential complications in some system scripts

You don't need `export` if the variable is already in the environment: any change of the value of the variable is reflected in the environment.¹ `PATH` is pretty much always in the environment; all unix systems set it very early on (usually in the very first process, in fact).

At login time, you can rely on `PATH` being already in the environment, and already containing some system directories. If you're writing a script that may be executed early while setting up some kind of virtual environment, you may need to ensure that `PATH` is non-empty and exported: if `PATH` is still unset, then something like `PATH=$PATH:/some/directory` would set `PATH` to `:/some/directory`, and the empty component at the beginning means the current directory (like `.:/some/directory`).

```
if [ -z "${PATH-}" ]; then export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin; fi
```

#### Notes on shells other than bash

In bash, ksh and zsh, `export` is special syntax, and both `PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH` and `export PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH` do the right thing even. In other Bourne/POSIX-style shells such as dash (which is `/bin/sh` on many systems), `export` is parsed as an ordinary command, which implies two differences:

- `~` is only parsed at the beginning of a word, except in assignments (see [How to add home directory path to be discovered by Unix which command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25605/how-to-add-home-directory-path-to-be-discovered-by-unix-which-command/25704#25704) for details);
- `$PATH` outside double quotes [breaks if `PATH` contains whitespace or `\[*?`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

So in shells like dash, <strike>`export PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH`</strike> sets `PATH` to the literal string `~/opt/bin/:` followed by the value of `PATH` up to the first space.
`PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH` (a bare assignment) [doesn't require quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748) and does the right thing. If you want to use `export` in a portable script, you need to write `export PATH="$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH"`, or `PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH; export PATH` (or `PATH=$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH; export PATH` for portability to even the Bourne shell that didn't accept `export var=value` and didn't do tilde expansion).

¹  <sub>This wasn't true in Bourne shells (as in the actual Bourne shell, not modern POSIX-style shells), but you're highly unlikely to encounter such old shells these days.</sub>

Comment: Still not able to understand the complication with export. can you please simplify it?

Comment: @priojeetpriyom Simple explanation: you don't need `export`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, perfectly detailed. You say "*You should not define environment variables in ~/.bashrc*", but unfortunately 100% of the programs that I have installed on my system that modify the path (FZF and Rust's Cargo) modify the path in `.bashrc`. I assume because FZF is written in Rust too it's following the pattern of Rust.

Comment: could it also be `export PATH` ...

Comment: What about when the element being added to $PATH is an environment variable set inside ~/.bashrc?

Comment: As detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415028/137608), this basic form of adding to path should likely be replaced by a more robust version.

Comment: @TomRussell: you shouldn't be setting your environment variables in .bashrc, since that is specifically for interactive shells and you want your variables available to non-interactive shells too.

Comment: Does it matter if we put it in `.zshrc` or `zprofile`?

Comment: @BenCarp `.zshrc` only works for programs started via a terminal. `.zprofile` applies to all programs. (Except on macOS which does things differently and AFAIK doesn't have a way to run shell code to set environment variables.)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - Out of curiosity: why not linking to [an existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415028/137608) in section "Potential complications in some system scripts", which clearly explains the case, and what to do about it?
That would likely help readers (one of the main missions of SE), at least knowing better the pros and cons of using one form or another, and deciding based on that.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio That answer didn't exist when I posted mine. I also don't agree that it “clearly explains” the problem: it spends a lot of time explaining the solution before mentioning the reason in passing (and it doesn't even actually state what an empty path component means). The solution in that answer is also rather complex and usually not really relevant: when `PATH` is empty, you typically don't need to add one extra directory to it, but to populate it with some standard directories. So I show how to do this.

Comment: No single word about `/etc/profile.d/somefile.sh` which also could contain PATH segments. It is used quite a lot in automation because dropping entire file is simpler than dealing with specific lines in general files like `.profile`.

Comment: @Dzintars No shell has a rule to read `/etc/profile`. Many systems set up `/etc/profile` to read `/etc/profile.d/*`. If so you'll see the code to do that in `/etc/profile.d`.

Comment: Note that a fresh Ubuntu installation [does not read `.profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317282/set-environment-variables-for-gnome-on-wayland-and-bash-on-virtual-terminals-or) any more.

Answer (score 116):

### **The bullet-proof way of Appending/Prepending**

**The usual methods for appending/prepending**

```
PATH="$PATH:~/opt/bin"   # appending
PATH="~/opt/bin:$PATH"   # prepending
```

**may bring hard headaches.**

The **bullet-proof way** to add a path (e.g., `~/opt/bin`) to the PATH environment variable is

```
PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}~/opt/bin"   # appending
PATH="~/opt/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"   # prepending
```

**Why?**

This avoids the spurious leading/trailing colon when `$PATH` is initially empty, which can have undesired side effects and *can become a nightmare*, elusive to find ([this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176379/137608) briefly deals with the case the `awk`-way).

**Explanation** (from [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)):

> ```
> ${parameter:+word}
> ```
>
> If `parameter` is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of `word` is substituted.

Thus, `${PATH:+${PATH}:}` is expanded to:

1. nothing, if `PATH` is null or unset,
2. `${PATH}:`, if `PATH` is set.

**Note**: This is for bash.

---

I wonder why system scripts typically do not use this.
**EDIT**: I have just found that scripts like `devtoolset-6/enable` actually use this,

```
$ cat /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/enable
# General environment variables
export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
...
```

Comment: `${PATH:+:${PATH}}` is confusing because the first `:` is part of the syntax and the second `:` is the list delimiter.

Comment: Well, I guess you will have to get used to it.

Comment: `:` is context-sensitive. It's a rudimentary form of AI. :-)

Comment: this `:+` is acceptable to include in `.profile`, [since that's POSIX compatible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389659/281153), right?

Comment: This is awfully repetitive... can't we shorten this somehow? I mean, `PATH` is not that long a word, by I don't want to have to do the same for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CPLUSINCLUDE_PATH` etc.

Comment: @einpoklum - Not that I know of. 
Anyway, you copy-paste it as many times as you need it (would that be 10? 20?), almost once and for all. That is about 3 minutes. I don't think it's even worth trying to come up with a shorter version, but if you find some, you are welcome to edit the post.
Compared to the trouble it may occasionally bring if you don't use this, there is no doubt one *should* use this.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: Personally, I decided to go with allowing a redundant `:` initially, then after filling up my PATH with everything, "scrubbing" the PATH by removing dupes and empty entries, along the lines of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176379/34868).

Comment: What about `"$p/bin${PATH:+:}$PATH"` like shown in [Nix Pill 12](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/inputs-design-pattern.html)? Seems legit and marginally simpler (less braces) to me

Answer (score 105):

Either way works, but they don't do the same thing: the elements of `PATH`are checked left to right. In your first example, executables in `~/opt/bin` will have precedence over those installed, for example, in `/usr/bin`, which may or may not be what you want.

In particular, from a safety point of view, it is dangerous to add paths to the front, because if someone can gain write access to your `~/opt/bin`, they can put, for example, a different `ls` in there, which you'd then probably use instead of `/bin/ls` without noticing. Now imagine the same for `ssh` or your browser or choice... (The same goes triply for putting . in your path.)

Comment: But if you want to have your own, customized version of `ls`, you need to put it in a directory ahead of `/bin`.

Comment: or alias ls=myls

Answer (score 42):

I'm confused by question 2 (since removed from the question since it was due to an unrelated issue):

> What's a workable way to append more paths on different lines?
>   Initially I thought this could do the trick:
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin
> export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/node/bin
> ```
>
> but it doesn't because the second assignment doesn't only append
>   `~/opt/node/bin`, but also the whole `PATH` previously assigned.
>
> This is a possible workaround:
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin:~/opt/node/bin
> ```
>
> but for readability I'd prefer to have one assignment for one path.

If you say

```
PATH=~/opt/bin
```

that's **all** that will be in your PATH.  PATH is just an environment variable, and if you want to add to the PATH, you have to rebuild the variable with exactly the contents you want.  That is, what you give as an example to question 2 is exactly what you want to do, unless I'm totally missing the point of the question.

I use both forms in my code.  I have a generic profile that I install on every machine I work on that looks like this, to accommodate for potentially-missing directories:

```
export PATH=/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/contrib/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/X11
# add optional items to the path
for bindir in $HOME/local/bin $HOME/bin; do
    if [ -d $bindir ]; then
        PATH=$PATH:${bindir}
    fi
done
```

Comment: You are right about the example of question 2, it works. Another PATH related issue on my system confused me. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 28):

Linux determines the executable search path with the `$PATH` environment variable. To add directory /data/myscripts to the beginning of the `$PATH` environment variable, use the following:

```
PATH=/data/myscripts:$PATH
```

To add that directory to the end of the path, use the following command:

```
PATH=$PATH:/data/myscripts
```

But the preceding are not sufficient because when you set an environment variable inside a script, that change is effective only within the script. There are only two ways around this limitation:

- If within the script, you export the environment variable it is effective within any programs called by the script. Note that it is not effective within the program that called the script.
- If the program that calls the script does so by inclusion instead of calling, any environment changes in the script are effective within the calling program. Such inclusion can be done with the dot command or the source command.

Examples:

```
$HOME/myscript.sh
source $HOME/myscript.sh
```

Inclusion basically incorporates the "called" script in the "calling" script. It's like a #include in C. So it's effective inside the "calling" script or program. But of course, it's not effective in any programs or scripts called by the calling program. To make it effective all the way down the call chain, you must follow the setting of the environment variable with an export command.

As an example, the bash shell program incorporates the contents of file .bash_profile by inclusion. Place the following 2 lines in .bash_profile:

```
PATH=$PATH:/data/myscripts
export PATH
```

effectively puts those 2 lines of code in the bash program. So within bash, the $PATH variable includes `$HOME/myscript.sh`, and because of the export statement, any programs called by bash have the altered `$PATH` variable. And because any programs you run from a bash prompt are called by bash, the new path is in force for anything you run from the bash prompt.

The bottom line is that to add a new directory to the path, you must append or prepend the directory to the $PATH environment variable within a script included in the shell, and you must export the `$PATH` environment variable.

More information [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm)

Answer (score 27):

For some time now I've kept with me two functions `pathadd` and `pathrm` that assist in adding elements to the path without the need to worry about duplications.

`pathadd` takes a single path argument and an optional `after` argument which if supplied will append to the `PATH` otherwise it prepends it.

In almost every situation if you're adding to the path then you're likely wanting to override anything already in the path, which is why I opt to prepend by default.

```
pathadd() {
    newelement=${1%/}
    if [ -d "$1" ] && ! echo $PATH | grep -E -q "(^|:)$newelement($|:)" ; then
        if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
            PATH="$PATH:$newelement"
        else
            PATH="$newelement:$PATH"
        fi
    fi
}

pathrm() {
    PATH="$(echo $PATH | sed -e "s;\(^\|:\)${1%/}\(:\|\$\);\1\2;g" -e 's;^:\|:$;;g' -e 's;::;:;g')"
}
```

Put these in any script you wish to alter the PATH environment and you can now do.

```
pathadd "/foo/bar"
pathadd "/baz/bat" after
export PATH
```

You're guaranteed not to add to the path if it's already there. If you now want to ensure `/baz/bat` is at the start.

```
pathrm "/baz/bat"
pathadd "/baz/bat"
export PATH
```

Now any path can be moved to the front if it's already in the path without doubling.

Comment: Related and cleaner approach to check for presence of a directory in your PATH: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32054/135943

Comment: I've found it useful to add to this a check that the path exists as well, and silently ignore the call if it doesn't.

Comment: That check is already present @RogerDahl , the use of `-d`

Comment: (1) `echo $PATH` can mess up if `$PATH` contains field separators or glob characters.  Yeah, sure, you ‘‘shouldn’t’’ create directories with field separators or glob characters in their names, but why not handle that case correctly, when it’s so easy to do?  (2) Why the ***silent*** failure if the directory doesn’t exist?  If you type `pathadd "/opt/newprogran/bin"` and then `newprogram`, and you get a “command not found” error, how long will you scratch your head before you notice that you misspelled the directory in the `pathadd` command?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Your ``pathrm`` will fail if the argument contains `;`. Again, you ‘‘shouldn’t’’ create directories with semicolons in their names, but you should try harder to handle it (or at least document it as a weakness of your code).  (4) And `;::;:;` is fun to read … NOT!  (5) Your `pathrm` also fails ***silently*** if you mistype the argument.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': why won't the `[ -d "$1" ]` catch the case of a non-existent directory?  I haven't tested the code (because I have more own function which I prefer) but it seems like it should....

Comment: @iconoclast: We’re not understanding each other.  Including: I don’t understand your question.  But I guess your question is founded on a misunderstanding of what I said.  To clarify, ``[ -d "$1" ]`` certainly will fail (i.e., evaluate to false) if the directory doesn’t exist.  But look at the big picture: `if [ -d "$1" ] … ; then` *`(add to PATH)`* `fi` — there’s no `else` clause.  If the directory doesn’t exist, the function will not change the `PATH` — ***but it won’t issue an error message**,* so the user doesn’t know that it failed, and doesn’t understand why their program is “not found”.

Comment: ahhh, I see what you mean... "fail silently" from the point of view of the person issuing the command at the moment, even though it succeeds at ignoring non-existent directories (and therefore succeeds from the original programmer's point of view)

Answer (score 14):

I can't speak for other distributions, but Ubuntu has a file, /etc/environment, that is the default search path for all users. Since my computer is only used by me, I put any directories that I want in my path there, unless it is a temporary addition that I put in a script.

Answer (score 13):

To add a new path to the `PATH` environment variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/new-path/
```

For this change to be applied to every shell you open, add it to the file that the shell will *source* when it is invoked. In different shells this can be:

- Bash Shell: ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc or profile
- Korn Shell: ~/.kshrc or .profile
- Z Shell: ~/.zshrc  or .zprofile

e.g.

```
# export PATH=$PATH:/root/learning/bin/
# source ~/.bashrc
# echo $PATH
```

You can see the provided path in the above output.

Answer (score 10):

There are some situations where it using `PATH=/a/b:$PATH` might be considered the "incorrect" way to add a path to `PATH`:

1. Adding a path that's not actually a directory.
2. Adding a path that's already in `PATH` in the same form.
3. Adding a relative path (since the actual directory searched would change as you change the current working directory).
4. Adding a path that's already in `PATH` in a different form (i.e., an alias due to using symlinks or `..`).
5. If you avoid doing 4, not moving the path to the front of `PATH` when it's intended to override other entries in `PATH`.

This (Bash-only) function does the "right thing" in the above situations (with an exception, see below), returns error codes, and prints nice messages for humans. The error codes and messages can be disabled when they're not wanted.

```
prepath() {
    local usage="\
Usage: prepath [-f] [-n] [-q] DIR
  -f Force dir to front of path even if already in path
  -n Nonexistent dirs do not return error status
  -q Quiet mode"

    local tofront=false errcode=1 qecho=echo
    while true; do case "$1" in
        -f)     tofront=true;       shift;;
        -n)     errcode=0;          shift;;
        -q)     qecho=':';          shift;;
        *)      break;;
    esac; done
    # Bad params always produce message and error code
    [[ -z $1 ]] && { echo 1>&2 "$usage"; return 1; }

    [[ -d $1 ]] || { $qecho 1>&2 "$1 is not a directory."; return $errcode; }
    dir="$(command cd "$1"; pwd -P)"
    if [[ :$PATH: =~ :$dir: ]]; then
        $tofront || { $qecho 1>&2 "$dir already in path."; return 0; }
        PATH="${PATH#$dir:}"        # remove if at start
        PATH="${PATH%:$dir}"        # remove if at end
        PATH="${PATH//:$dir:/:}"    # remove if in middle
    fi
    PATH="$dir:$PATH"
}
```

The exception is that this function does not canonicalize paths added to `PATH` via other means, so if a non-canonical alias for a path is in `PATH`, this will add a duplicate. Trying to canonicalize paths already in `PATH` is a dicey proposition since a relative path has an obvious meaning when passed to `prepath` but when already in the path you don't know what the current working directory was when it was added.

Comment: regarding relative paths: what about having a '-r' switch, which would add the path without making it absolute first, and which would also look for it as absolute before adding it?    If this were script, one could use it in other shells. Is there any benefit of having it as a function?    nice code!

Comment: @hoijui It has to be a function because it's modifying the current environment. If it were a script, it would modify the environment of the subprocess running the script and, when the script exited you'd have the same `$PATH` as you had before. As for `-r`, no, I think that relative paths in `$PATH` are just too unreliable and weird (your path changes every time you `cd`!) to want to support something like that in a general tool.

Answer (score 8):

For me (on Mac OS X 10.9.5), adding the path name (e.g. `/mypathname`) to the file `/etc/paths` worked very well.

Before editing, `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

After editing `/etc/paths` and restarting the shell, the $PATH variable is appended with `/pathname`. Indeed, `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/mypathname
```

What happened is that `/mypathname` has been appended to the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Better to add a file to the /etc/paths.d directory than to edit the /etc/paths file itself.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution:

```
PATH=$(echo -n $PATH | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '!x[$0]++' | sed "s/\(.*\).\{1\}/\1/")
```

A nice easy one liner that doesn't leave a trailing `:`

Comment: -bash: awk: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory

Comment: @davidcondrey - awk and sed are very common external commands. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415028/137608) provides a pure-bash way of achieving the same, so it works even in cases when awk and/or sed are not present (or their respective directories are not in the path!)

Answer (score 2):

**POSIX-compliant**

```
pathedit()
{
    [ -z "$2" ] && return 2
    PATH=$(printf ":$PATH:" | sed "s:\:$2\::\::g")
    case $1 in
    -p ) PATH=$2$PATH ;;
    -a ) PATH=$PATH$2 ;;
    -r ) ;;
    * ) return 2 ;;
    esac
    PATH=$(printf "$PATH" | tr -s :) PATH=${PATH#:} PATH=${PATH%:}
}
```

`pathedit -p path` prepends path to $PATH
`pathedit -a path` appends path to $PATH
`pathedit -r path` removes path from $PATH

also removes extraneous colons

**without external commands (non-POSIX)**

```
pathedit()
{
    [[ -z $2 ]] && return 2
    PATH=:$PATH: PATH=${PATH//:$2:/}
    case $1 in
    -p ) PATH=$2$PATH ;;
    -a ) PATH=$PATH$2 ;;
    -r ) ;;
    * ) return 2 ;;
    esac
    while [[ $PATH == *::* ]] ; do
        PATH=${PATH//::/:}
    done
    PATH=${PATH#:} PATH=${PATH%:}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't respect paths with space characters and other characters which affect shell behavior (parentheses etc.)

Comment: @einpoklum - not sure what you mean as it works for me (with spaces, &c.)

Comment: Hmm... interesting.