# Somethings wrong with .bashrc

Tags: bash, zsh, path

I read a tutorial about how to add a folder to `PATH`. I added the below to the `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/opt/aseprite/build/bin
```

When I tried to use `source ./.bashrc` from `zsh`
I got this error

```
/home/luke/.bashrc:16: command not found: shopt
/home/luke/.bashrc:24: command not found: shopt
/home/luke/.bashrc:111: command not found: shopt
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:45: command not found: shopt
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1512: parse error near `|'
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$
```

Here is a link to my full `.bashrc`: https://pastebin.com/28RQV97K

What am I doing wrong with the `PATH` variable here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold:

#### 1. You overwrote the path specification

With your

```
export PATH=/opt/aseprite/build/bin
```

you have not added a folder to `PATH`, but overwritten it. Hence your bash cannot find any executables outside of `/opt/aseprite/build/bin` (unless you call them with absolute path).

What instead you should do is

```
export PATH="$PATH":/opt/aseprite/build/bin
```

This would append the new path to the existing content of the variable.

**However**, and more importantly:

#### 2. You used the wrong configuration file

If you are using `zsh`, then the `.bashrc` is the wrong file to use for shell settings. The two shells are rather different in how they handle environment settings and what syntax to use, so you may not get the expected results even if the syntax is correct for the `bash`. The errors you show demonstrate how the `zsh` fails to apply `bash`-specific commands and settings, which would probably have worked fine had you sourced the file from a `bash` (in particular, `shopt` is a `bash` builtin command which `zsh` cannot know).

Instead, look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31193/377345) on how to add paths to `zsh` .

Fortunately, since you only `sourced` the `.bashrc`, the wrong settings will only take effect in the terminal where you ran that command, and opening a new console will give you a fresh start (since `zsh` doesn't automatically read your incorrectly modified `.bashrc`).