# Path is there, but cannot call one program without specifying path

Tags: path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

I installed "perf" on Linux.
But I can only use it by specifying the path: `~/bin/perf`

I checked path by using `echo` and I found `/bin` is there.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~/bin` is not `/bin`. Add it to `$PATH`.

Comment: but I got this, why? " `/home/paul/bin': not a valid identifier
"

Comment: @AndersLind: get rid of the whitespace. It should be `export PATH=foo:bar:baz`, not `export PATH = foo:bar:baz`. Shells are sensitive to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

You have to *add* `~/bin` to $PATH. You can do it with this command :

```
export PATH="$PATH":~/bin
```

You can check your PATH variable with `env` :

```
env | grep  ^PATH=
```

Comment: Another way to check PATH variable is simply `echo $PATH`.