# How do I specify which version of the PostgreSQL client (psql) to run?

Tags: postgresql, shell

Here's my situation: I have two versions of PostgreSQL installed on my CentOS system, and with the two versions come two different `psql` interactive terminals.

One is located at `/usr/bin/psql`, and starts when I run `psql -U username`

Another newer one is located at `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql`.

I want the newer one to start by default when I run `psql` from the command line. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, to avoid symlinks, and to avoid changing your `$PATH`, you could add your command to the hash table:

```
hash -p /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql psql
```

This will put your command into the command hash table and it will be executed before any other command (in fact, no path search will be performed).

If you used a command called `psql` before, then it already sits in the hash table and it will be the first hit when searching for commands. In that case, remove the old entry first by typing

```
hash -d psql
```

and then issue the command above. You can source it in your `.bashrc` should you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your [`PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) so that `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/` (the newer one) comes before `/usr/bin/`.

A less package-manager-safe safe alternative is to move/remove/rename the `psql` in `/usr/bin/` and create a symlink in `/usr/bin/` to the new one (not tested):

```
> cd /usr/bin
# move the old one however you like
> ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql .
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you do *not* alter `/usr/bin/psql` if you are on any distro other than maybe slackware. It will get replaced when an update to the postgresql packages are applied. It's a really, really, bad idea. Change your `PATH` instead.