# Change PATH in Debian 7.1.0 for Java

Tags: debian, path, java

I would like to change the PATH of my Debian 7.1.0 system to link to the Java version I want. If I enter in the terminal:

```
java -version
```

I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

This is the Java version preinstalled by my distribution. I have now downloaded the Sun JDK 1.7.0 update 25. I would like my system to use this version instead of the preinstalled version. I have made two changes to my `PATH` in `.bashrc` but I still have the same Java version.

My `.bashrc` file contains the lines:

```
PATH="PATH":/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_25
export PATH
```

Comment: Ok. Now it works. I have to add /bin and restart the current session

Comment: It works but I lost the original PATH and the possibility to use all the command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you actually want is this in your `~/.profile` (or `.bashrc` if you insist, but `.profile` is [better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/22222)):

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_25/bin
export PATH
```

You were losing the original $PATH because you were using `"PATH"` instead of `$PATH` so it was interpreted as a simple string and all you were doing is setting your path to:

```
PATH:/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_25/bin
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want the oracle java bin *prepended* (not appended) to your path:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_25/bin:$PATH
```

Since the execution path is a list of directories that are checked *in order* (so if you *append* the jdk7 bin to $PATH, the distro java found be found first instead).

> I lost the original PATH and the possibility to use all the command

Notice the difference between these two:

```
PATH=$PATH
PATH=PATH
```

When you *assign* to a shell variable, use just the word, `PATH`.  When you reference a shell variable, you must prefix it with `$`.  For example:

```
FOO="hello"
FOO=$FOO" world"
```

`$FOO` now equals "hello world".  But:

```
FOO="hello"
FOO=FOO" world"
```

`$FOO` now equals "FOO world".

Don't overwrite `$PATH` -- append or prepend to it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, the Java path can also be set via

```
/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
```

If you take a look at `/etc/profile`, you'll see that it sources all the scripts inside `/etc/profile.d/`.