# path in environment variable PATH, but command still not found

Tags: path

I am working with a Redhat distribution.  Mysql is installed with the binary in the following path:

```
/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql
```

Furthermore, the environmental variable PATH echos:

```
echo $PATH
/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql
```

The server has been restarted but if I type

```
mysql
```

into bash it returns the following:

```
# mysql -u root
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

Please advise

**EDIT**

Altered PATH EV to

```
/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin
```

using

```
export  mysql /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin
export  PATH  ${mysql}:${PATH}
```

Still get `command not found`

After rebooting the server, echo $PATH is now:

```
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

So, the path to mysql is gone.

Comment: Run `/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql -u root`, what is the result?

Comment: Did you run `export PATH`?

Comment: If I fully qualify the path for mysql, then the client utility starts.

Comment: Why is it installed in `root`'s subdir?  Most users (including the `mysql` user) __cannot__ read or search in `root`'s subdir.  Probably works when you type the path yourself since you're already root.  Your directory structure implies it would work just dandy in `/opt/rh/...` ... move it there, make owned by `mysql:mysql` and be done with it.

Comment: That's where the admin put it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add only the path, not the `mysql` executable itself. `PATH` is list of directories, not files.

Try adding:

```
/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/
```

Comment: i changed it but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @AndroidAddict: Did you add to `PATH` of your user? Can you give output `locate bin/mysql`?

Comment: I don't think so.  I don't know what that means?

Comment: @AndroidAddict: What ouput when you run `locate bin/mysql`?

Comment: Command not found

Comment: I just rebooted the server and echoed $PATH.  Now, the path to mysql is gone!  How do I make it permanent?

Comment: Add the line to your `.bashrc`, refer to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: Would you please help me find it?  might I use `find / -name .bachrc type -f` ?

Comment: It is located in `/home/youruser/.bashrc`

Comment: Okay, I am in home folder for root and I don't see that file.

Comment: Just create it. You should read `man bash` to see more details.

Comment: Okay, I created .bashrc in my home user directory.  I still get command not found.  I have rebooted and echoed PATH and the path to mysql is still not in PATH.

Comment: run `echo -e "PATH=$PATH:/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/\nexport PATH" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @dchirikov now I cannot use mysql at all, even from the directory.  Please advise

Comment: execute `PATH=/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql; export PATH`

Comment: Why is `/root/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql` in there twice?