# bash: adduser: command not found on centOS

Tags: shell, path

I installed CentOS 5.5 on my VMWare 8 recently and I am trying to add a new user on the system. I am unable to add the user unless I use `su -` option. I believe it has to do something with path not set properly.

I updated the path and here is what it looks like 
`/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/uone/bin:/sbin`

I believe the command is in /sbin dir which is already a part of path. Can anyone suggest me what else I might be missing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try adding `/usr/sbin` to your path.

For example to add it to the end of the path you would do something like this:

`export PATH=$PATH:/the/file/path`

Comment: Yep! That did the trick, Added it as priority location in path. Thanks mdpc :)

Comment: How would I do that? There is already a PATH = something in my .bash_profile? How do i add another one?

Comment: @xiaodai http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/24354

Comment: Want to provide an example of that for this to be a complete answer?

Answer (score 23):

I know the OP answer was solved, however for those who are running CentOS from within the docker container, which appears to be missing both *adduser* and *useradd*, the solution is to install **shadow-utils** (under *root* obviously):

```
yum install shadow-utils
```

Answer (score 8):

```
/usr/sbin/useradd username -g groupname -d homedirectory
```

Comment: Its giving me error -bash: /usr/sbin/useradd: No such file or directory

Comment: same here @NishadUp

Comment: you first need to install shadow-utils package and then use the /usr/sbin/useradd command. It should work this way. Maybe you did not install the shadow-utils in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

```
whereis useradd
```

this is used to solve that problem

Comment: That only tries to *find* useradd, not install it.

Comment: `whereis: command not found`