# How can a run a compiled java or c program from a shell file from outside its directory?

Tags: linux, shell-script, raspberry-pi

So, in a directory `/home/pi/remoteinfo/temp/code`  is have a C program called `a.out` and a shell file called `tempstart.sh`.

Inside the tempstart.sh file is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.out
```

Now, when I am in `/home/pi/remoteinfo/temp/code` I can type `./tempstart.sh` and my program will begin execution.

But when I try to run `tempstart.h` from anywhere outside its directory I get
`line 3: ./a.out: No such file or directory`.

What is happening and how can I fix it?

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 with the default OS

Comment: See [how to execute a bash script without typing ./](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162134/how-to-execute-a-bash-script-without-typing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that the script will run the command `./a.out` in the present working directory, as that's what's written into the script; if you run the script from somewhere else, your binary is *not in* the present working directory, causing the shell to throw the error you're seeing.

If you want to use the script to invoke the binary regardless of the directory from which it is invoked, you have at least four options:

- Put `a.out` into a directory that is already in your `PATH` and stop specifying the present working directory as the location of `a.out` (e. g. move `a.out` to `$HOME/bin/a.out`, and change the script to simply run `a.out` rather than `./a.out`).
- Have the script explicitly call the full path to the binary (e. g. rather than `./a.out`, instead `/path/to/the/location/of/a.out`)
- Have the script add to *its* `PATH` the location of the script, and don't specify the current directory as the location of the binary (e. g. `PATH="$PATH:/path/to/the/binary"; a.out`
- Have the script *set* the working directory to the location of the script before trying to run it (e. g. `cd /path/to/the/binary; ./a.out`)

Answer (score 0):

`./script.sh` would assume that you're running it in the same directory.

Say `a.out` is in `/var/run/a.out`, you could change `tempstart.sh` to contain that full filepath.

At which point you could run the script from anywhere (provided `a.out` itself doesn't require you to be in a certain directory when running it).