# How to add my MATLAB to PATH?

Tags: shell, path

I have read this thread on how to correctly add the paths:

[How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

I have already exported path

```
/usr/local/proc_mt/bin:usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin
```

Still I do not know how should I change my matlab shell script, in a way that would enable me to use the matlab.

Comment: Did you notice that you're missing a slash `/` at the beginning of `usr/local/MATLAB`... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shell script, simply include the following:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/proc_mt/bin:usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin"
```

If there are executables with the same name as other executables in your `$PATH`, and you wish to give the Matlab executables preference over the others, put it *before* your current environment `$PATH` like so:

```
PATH="/usr/local/proc_mt/bin:usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin:$PATH"
```

In some scenarios you may need to export this environment variable by doing

`export PATH=[the solutions I listed above]`

...which can never hurt (and in some cases may make obscure issues easier to troubleshoot)

The issue you are probably experiencing is that you are setting the `$PATH` in your shell, and the actual script is defaulting to the default environment `$PATH`.  You can avoid this, as said before, by explicitly setting the `$PATH` from within the script itself.

Comment: Are you thinking of matlab shell script?Should I change the ownership?
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 58454 Dez 29  2014 matlab

Comment: Only if you are running it as root. Otherwise, `chown` to the user who will be running the script.  If the name of your script is simply `matlab` and there is also an executable in your `$PATH` called `matlab`, then that is your problem.  Change the name of the script to `somethingelse.sh`

Comment: but how did you find the location of the binaries files or MATLAB in the first place?

Comment: What is proc_mt suppose to be? this doesn't work for me, how did u find out what directory paths to put in there?

Comment: @CharlieParker - that's just part of this specific user's `$PATH`, which is a directory (probably unrelated to MATLAB) that includes executable files which can be referenced directly by name rather than their full path. My answer was not MATLAB-specific; it answered the question of how to correctly set a `$PATH` environment variable for a shell script. One must find one's own `$PATH` by executing `echo $PATH`. If you want a script that uses MATLAB executables, find where they exist, and include `export PATH="/path/to/MATLAB/bin/directory:${PATH}"` in your shell script.

Comment: Note: if you do it this way and there are executables in that directory that share a name with other executables found further along in your `$PATH`  -- say `/usr/bin` for example -- if MATLAB has an executable called `find`, it will be referenced instead of the normal `find` command located in `/usr/bin`, which you would have to reference by full path in order to execute it in the script.  If there are no executables with the same name, or you want the usual ones to take precedence, put the MATLAB bin directory at the end of your `$PATH`: `export PATH="${PATH}:/path/to/MATLAB/bin/directory"`.