# No paths getting set on login - bash not loading correctly?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, path, virtualenv

I don't know if this is because of virtualenv, but I ran the virtualenv command to set up a tensorflow environment. Now no paths get loaded at all. Nothing works. To do even basic commands (such as `ls`), I have to run the full script (`/bin/ls`). I cannot do anything at all unless I manually run export all the paths:

```
$ export PATH=/bin/:$PATH
```

etc.

Even after logging out and back in (through SSH), nothing loads.

Interestingly enough, `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` both get loaded (but not succesfully, since they cannot run some of the commands like `source`). Also I should note that I don't have root access on this machine, so I can't change (or break for that matter) anything globally.

I couldn't get out of the virtualenv either, since "deactivate" didn't work.

What did I break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably overwritten your `$PATH` variable, instead of [extending](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) it.

In one of your shell startup files, you probably have an assignment such as

```
PATH="/some/path"
```

instead of

```
PATH="/some/path:$PATH"
```

Try to find out where you assign to `PATH` and make sure they never **replace** `$PATH` but **extend** it:

```
/usr/bin/grep 'PATH=' ~/.bash*
```

If you cannnot find what is wrong right away, update your answer with pertinent snippets from those files.

As a workaround until you have fixed the errors in your shell script, you can look at `/etc/profile` where the system-wide `$PATH` is defined in most Linux/BSD distros. Running

```
`export PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin"`
```

should give you access to all tools installed in standard location.

The point of virtualenv is that you define your environments on a per-project basis so as to **not** clutter your shell startup files with environment-specific code. Remove (comment out) all the setup scripts related to it and rely on the `virtualenv` tool to create/update a per-directory environment for you.

Comment: You were right. It was a stupid mistake in a dotfile where I left out the `$` in one of the exports.