# How to set the path of a batch environment to find the location of the "qsub" command

Tags: path, cluster, batch-jobs

I have a program, called "minvappmpi", which is parallelised and itself calls qsub as a subroutine.

When I use the program on the cluster, it throws the error

```
qsub: command not found
```

If I want to submit another job using "qsub", then everything is fine. It is only when I call "qsub" inside my program that somehow the command is not found.

I think the issue is something to do with paths: somehow the environment I am working in knows where the executable "qsub" is sitting, but the cluster doesn't?

I'd like to know: firstly, how to make sure what the path is for the batch environment, and if it is different to the one for the login environment, and, secondly, if there is a way to change the path for the batch environment without root permissions?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: For a guide to setting up "PATH", see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path .  If that doesn't help, you'll need to expand on "When I submit a job using the program on the cluster" - how do you submit this job?  `at`, `cron`, something custom to the machine in question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry to have been vague...I meant submit to an SGE cluster (hence qsub). I think the cluster is managed via Torque, if that is useful to know...

Comment: Oh, is `qsub` the command that submits a job?  I can't follow which program is calling (or trying to call) `qsub`, and what program `qsub` itself is submitting.  Does "submit a job using the program" mean "use the program to submit a job", or "submit (a job that uses the program)"?

Comment: Yes! Sorry...I guess I was a bit vague earlier :-) I have re-edited the question to make it more clear!

Comment: If `qsub` is an executable on the system, how does minvappmpi call it "as a subroutine"?  Does it use eg. the [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function, as in `system("qsub")`?

Answer (score 3):

Okay! I have made progress!

I tried submitting my job with

```
qsub -V run.sh
```

As I learned that this exports all the variables in qsub's command environment to the batch environment. This worked great, and now the batch environment knows where "qsub" is :-).

But I have a new problem.

I need to submit jobs on the cluster with

```
qsub -P Projectname
```

And my program doesn't know that! It just calls "qsub".

Is there any way I can get around this without having to recompile? I don't want to have to recompile because I'm running the program remotely and I don't have all the right libraries on the remote machine (and can't install them without root permissions :-))

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It sounds like `qsub -V` is the correct fix for your original problem, so you should end your answer after that.  The second part, about running with extra command-line options, is a new question.