# How can I use ifuse command in a bash script?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path, .desktop

When I enter this command **in a terminal window**, it works as expected:

```
ifuse "/home/sadi/mnt"
```

But it is ineffective when used in a bash script **run via a .desktop file**.

What can I do to use it like that?

This command (supposed to mount a connected device in the specified folder) is preceded by `mkdir -p "/home/sadi/mnt"`, and followed by `nautilus --no-desktop --new-window "/home/sadi/mnt"` both of which work perfectly both in terminal and in bash script.

`type ifuse` output = `/home/sadi/usr/bin/ifuse` and I have this in my `.bashrc`: `export PATH="${HOME}/usr/bin:${PATH}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51475/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-sadi).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the PATH inside `~/.bashrc`, but `~/.bashrc` is only fully sourced if the starting shell is interactive.

It is usual to have an statement equivalent to:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return  # If not running interactively, don't do anything
```

Which will make your setting of PATH:

```
export PATH="${HOME}/usr/bin:${PATH}"
```

simply in-effective if placed after the test for `PS1` when used inside a no-interactive script.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is **What can I do to use the command ifuse like that?**

Comment: @Sadi Place the PATH setting command before the `[ -z "$PS1 ]` ?. Place a PATH command in `~/.profile` (so all scripts will have the correct PATH set) ? Set the PATH in `~/.bash_profile` so only bash is affected by the PATH change ?

Comment: **Thank you very much!** I haven't studied this area yet ;-) Simply adding the new PATH section at the end of `~/.profile` did the trick although it includes `~/.bashrc` earlier which includes `If not running interactively, don't do anything` strings.