# Different bash profile files are loaded? For local and ssh-remote access to Cygwin

Tags: bash, ssh, openssh, cygwin, profile

I have installed `g++` package on Cygwin. so I see the following output in Cygwin:

```
Input:$ which g++
Output: /cygdrive/c/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin
```

I have also installed `openssh` package on Cygwin and configured an ssh server. However, when I connect remotely to my Cygwin I have the following output:

```
Input:$ which g++
Output: no g++ in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redis ....
```

How can I resolve the above issue? Is there any specific `./bash_profile` file that is loaded in the case of remote ssh to Cygwin? If yes, can I fix the issue by adding the following line to this `./bash_profile`:?

```
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put the change of PATH in your `~/.bashrc`
As reported in the code it will be set for

```
# base-files version 4.1-1

# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for interactive shells.
```

Comment: No: that file is not read when bash is a login shell, only when bash is an interactive non-login shell. And when bash is not a login shell, it shouldn't change environment variables. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: @Gilles The link that you showed says that `~/.bashrc` is not read for login shells. However, I changed the PATH in `~/.bashrc` and the login bash shell is reading that. I think this is another weird behavior of Cygwin.

Comment: @Admia You may have a `.bash_profile` that loads `.bashrc`. Put the `PATH` change in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Gilles Right. I just checked it and could see that my `.bash_profile` loads `.bashrc`.