# Creating shortcuts/alias's in Fedora

Tags: shell, alias

How do I create a shortcut/alias in fedora?
For example this is the path to my netbeans IDE

```
netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans
```

I am a lazy person, and I don't want to type all this out in the terminal, is there a way so I can type something else and it "equals" whatever I want?
Example
If I type

```
SOMECOMMAND = netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans
```

Whatever somecommand actually is, it will act as though I actually typed out the full

```
netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alias nb='netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans'
```

will probably do what you want.

Then `nb` gets expanded to the full command.

To see all the aliases you have set, type `alias`.
To unset the alias, you want `unalias nb`.

This alias won't be saved permanently. To do that you will need to edit your shell configuration. For bash, which is the default shell under Fedora, that's `.bashrc` in your home directory.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work

Comment: You need to give more information. Does `netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans` on its own actually do what you want?

Comment: yes, when I type that in the terminal it runs netbeans like it should

Comment: And what error message do you get from the suggested commands?

Comment: this is what it outputs: bash: alias: nb: not found bash: alias: =netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans: not found

Comment: Did you add an extra space by mistake?

Comment: I don't think I've ever face palmed so hard in my life, thank you!

Comment: I take it your command was `alias nb ='netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans'`. If you have an alias set, `alias <something>` prints what that alias is. And `alias <something> <somethingelse>` prints the value of both aliases. So your shell thought you were trying to print the value of both aliases, instead of assigning an alias. That should help understand your error message.

Comment: @bit.con Note that this alias will only work in a specific directory, the one containing `netbeans-8.2`. It would probably make more sense to put a full path there. But in fact what would make the most sense would be to [add `…/netbeans-8.2/bin` to your PATH](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path).