# Alternative to typing the path for /sbin/ifconfig

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, path

Everytime I need to access ifconfig , I find using using /sbin/ifconfig. If I need to directly type ifconfig in bash and get the required output without calling the directory every time, what should I do?

Comment: add `/sbin` to your `PATH`: `export PATH="/sbin:$PATH"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `/sbin` to your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). In the file `.profile` in your home directory, add the line

```
PATH="$PATH:/sbin"
```

See [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) for more information.

If you only want `ifconfig` and not other commands from `/sbin`, you could add an alias. In the `.bashrc` in your home directory, add

```
alias ifconfig=/sbin/ifconfig
```

`/sbin` only contains commands that are rarely useful when not running as [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser). `ifconfig` is an edge case: ordinary users can look at the current settings, but only root can change the settings. It's one of the few command that is typically placed in `/sbin` yet is commonly useful to ordinary users.

Under Linux, you can display mostly the same information with `ip addr`.