# Add application installed in another disk to the application list CentOS

Tags: centos

After installing application to a mounted disk using `rpm  -i --prefix=/some/other/path/ packagename.rpm` it is possible to open it using sh command. But it does not appear in application list and cannot search as well. is there any way to add these application to applications list.

Ex: I installed Atom to a mounted disk. To open Atom I have to go to the directory. Cannot search it by pressing super key and searching.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add `/some/other/path` to `PATH` environment variable.

Check out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) to find out how to do this.

Comment: I tried adding it to the path.But still it doesn't appear

Comment: @Choxmi Have you logged out and in? You have to do that or source a .bashrc.