# How do I change my path when executing a command following a terminal ssh to another machine

Tags: bash, ssh, python, path

For the following please consider that I'm new to the Linux file system and have little understanding here.

When I log onto my cluster I do so on a default machine. The admin have setup several python distributions in the root and I've set the one that I want to use in my .bashrc. In my case and for illustration this distribution is:

```
export PATH="/csoft/epd-7.3.2/bin:$PATH";
```

I've been asked to execute scripts from another machine that I have to ssh to via the terminal. When I ssh to this machine that file system appears exactly the same (including the .bashrc). However, a different version of python is executed by default. How do I set the path for this ssh machine, those unique name can be determined via hostname?

Comment: "the path" meaning: "how do I execute a specific version of python"?

Comment: is the file path relative to the root. In my case:

Comment: export PATH="/csoft/epd-7.3.2/bin:$PATH"; in the .bashrc. This is the path to the python that I need. The sys admins have several other python distributions that you can choose by setting this path appropriately.

Comment: so you need that particular $PATH set on a particular machine? Does `hostname` or `uname -n` return a unique value on that "other" machine that will uniquely identify it?

Comment: Yes it does have a unique name.

Comment: I'll propose a solution; in the meantime, you should [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/398154/edit) to include these critical details. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've made edits. If these don't completely suffice please feel free to edit yourself or leave sugggestions as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .bash_profile, include this (replacing unique-hostname-here with the output from `uname -n` on that host):

```
case $(uname -n) in
  (unique-hostname-here) PATH="/csoft/epd-7.3.2/bin:$PATH"
        ;;
esac
```

This presumes that the PATH variable has already been populated and exported previously (or subsequently); no need to re-export it every time it's set.

Further reading on shell initialization files:

- [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/117549)