# Flip between openmpi and mpich as default using linux terminal

Tags: bash, path

I need to run a code using mpicc(parallel gcc). A server has two packages of mpicc installed namely `OPENMPI` and `MPICH` at `/usr/local/OPENMPI` and `/usr/local/MPICH` respectively. By default mpicc of OPENMPI is being used

```
which mpicc
```

shows `/usr/local/OPENMPI/bin/mpicc`

My code is built for MPICH. Instead of calling mpicc of MPICH using full path every time. Is there an easy way of making `/usr/local/MPICH/bin/mpicc` as default until I complete my work and later change it back to `/usr/local/OPENMPI/bin/mpicc`

Comment: ln -sf /usr/local/OPENMPI/bin/mpicc /usr/local/bin if you do that it works?

Comment: In some systems (like Fedora) there are `modules` that allow you to change the enviroment for certain libraries/compilers. For example `module load mpich`/`module swap open-mpi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an `alias` would work perfectly for your situation.  You can add the following to your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`:

```
alias mympicc='/usr/local/MPICH/bin/mpicc'
```

A more permanent (but still reversible) solution is to add the `MPICH` location to your path BEFORE the `OPENMPI` location.  Easily done by adding the following your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/MPICH/bin:$PATH"
```

When you type a command like `mpicc`, if it's not in your current directory, your shell will search the `PATH` for it, in order, so it is important which position you put it to set precedence.

If you want to have some sort of a switch that you can use to easily "flip" between the two, you could make some sort of function and add it to your `.bashrc` (or `.profile`/`.bash_profile` [?](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)):

```
use_mpicc () {
    shopt -s nocasematch
    case "$1" in
        mpich) export PATH="...:/usr/local/MPICH/bin:/usr/local/OPENMPI/bin:..." ;;
        openmpi) export PATH="...:/usr/local/OPENMPI/bin:/usr/local/MPICH/bin:..." ;;
        *) return 1 ;;
    esac
    shopt -u nocasematch
}
```

In this example I have used ellipsis in place of your actual path.  I recommend actually specifying the full path in this function (if used) rather than using the: `PATH="Stuff_I_Need_added:$PATH"` method as that will just keep adding to your `PATH` every time you call the function, potentially causing it to become obnoxiously long.

You would call this like:

```
$ use_mpicc mpich
$ # OR
$ use_mpicc openmpi
```

More reading on setting your [path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/237982)