# Commands not found on Debian9 stretch OS

Tags: debian, command-not-found

I need to add commands found in /usr/bin to my root/home directory search path because I recently formatted my dell inspiron amd64 bit with Debian 9 stretch. I only installed the core os without any additional software.  So now, each time I tried running sudo on my home directory or if I try running any commands on my root account,  I keep getting an error message that such commands cannot be found. From my little research online , I have come to know that I need to add those commands to either my home or root search path.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please add the output of `echo $PATH`. [You can edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/435341/edit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Comment: And if you did a truly minimal install, many/most of those commands (like `sudo`) may not even be installed.  Please post your `$PATH` variable contents (`echo $PATH`) and *exactly* what command you are trying to run.

Comment: I tried running the sudo command but I kept getting the "command not found ". This is what is in my path after running echo $PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Answer (score 3):

To see your path type:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin
```

To append /usr/bin to your path immediately, type:

```
$ PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

To make sure /usr/bin remains in your path after next login, add(or edit) the PATH variable to your rc file (in my case .bashrc):

Check shell:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

My shell is bash, so I edit my .bashrc file:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line (or edit the PATH line if it already exists):

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

Comment: Thanks,  but where in the bashrc file should I add the new path to? Should it be before the last FI or after it.

Comment: You can safely add it to the bottom of the file.