# How to make alias for atom?

Tags: linux, alias, snap, atom

In linux mint, is it possible to run atom editor by command atom? I tried

```
atom
Command 'atom' is available in '/snap/bin/atom'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
atom: command not found
```

Comment: You need to add '/snap/bin' directory to the PATH environment variable as the error shows see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: What shell are you using? The default bash, or something else?

Comment: I'm using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Add the `/snap/bin` directory to you `$PATH`.  This would give you direct access to *any* command in that directory.

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin
   ```

   (this would go in your `~/.bashrc` file, for example).
2. Create an alias called `atom` that calls `/snap/bin/atom`. This would replace `atom` with `/snap/bin/atom` if you used the word as a command on the command line.

   ```
   alias atom=/snap/bin/atom
   ```

   (this could also be added to your `~/.bashrc` file).

   Instead of an alias, you could have a simple shell function that does the same thing:

   ```
   atom () { /snap/bin/atom "$@"; }
   ```

Changes to `~/.bashrc` would be activated when you start a new shell.

Comment: why do we need to use "$@" at the end of a shell function ? what happens if we don't use it ?
As I understand $@ - expands to the list of positional parameters, but we are not passing any parameters when we call atom.

Comment: @HarshaD To be totally honest, I have never used `atom`. I added the possibility to pass command line options to the function, because the alias allows it, and I didn't think it would hurt.  If you want to _disallow_ passing arguments to `atom`, then by all means remove the `"$@"` bit from the function.

Comment: When launching a text editor from the command line, it's pretty common to pass parameters, in particular the filename for a file to be edited, so most often when you see shell functions, etc., to launch editors, they'll end with "$@". The main reason I'd launch a GUI text editor from the command line is to pass parameters.