# How do I fix the "processing-java: command not found" error in the terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, path, sublime-text

I have installed processing-3.5.3 IDE but really want to use the Sublime text editor as my goto for processing sketches. What I have done so far:

1. Install the "Processing" package in sublime.
2. Installed processing-java in /home/testuser/Downloads/Compressed/processing-3.5.3-linux64/processing-3.5.3

I believe there must be an issue with my PATH to processing-java but no matter what I do I am unable to get to work. I also use the "processing-java --help" but it always returns "processing-java: command not found" in the terminal. 
OS: Pop!OS
Thanks
Kluivert

Comment: Do you get the same error when running `processing-java` in your Terminal?

Comment: You can try this solution : [How to run Processing applications from the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787093/how-to-run-processing-applications-from-the-terminal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're right, you need to add `process-java` to your PATH environmental variable. See this [detailed guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) on how to achieve this, but it should be something like this (though I'd recommend moving the binary elsewhere):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/testuser/Downloads/Compressed/processing-3.5.3-linux64/processing-3.5.3"
```

Also take note that you can [use Processing with pure Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104841/processing-in-java-without-ide).