# how to add home directory to path variable

Tags: linux

Im using gedit to type my script as an assignment and one of the questions is adding my home directory to the BEGINNING of the path variable and I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you scripting in? Gedit has nothing to do with this, which is basically asking “how to change the PATH variable”

Comment: im using /bin/bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Answer (score 2):

Simple way would be to use:

```
PATH=$HOME:$PATH
```