# Unpack Node.js to a custom folder and perform paths setup

Tags: path, node.js

I want to unpack [Node.js (Linux Binaries (x64))](https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz) to a custom folder and use it for a few projects.

The difficulties appear when I start using console. I can't use `npm` at all and I've got no idea how to install global modules in this case.

For instance, I install `gulp -g` and even specify the installation path for it, but when I wish to use `gulp`, it doesn't work.

So, again, I do not use package managers and `/usr/lib` folders, the whole node.js package in one, single folder. How to use it that way if possible at all?

There may be a few more Node.js versions there and it would be greate to have a way of setting up the `/paths/variables` for the selected `/folder/version` of Node.js.

Comment: You will have to add that directory to your PATH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks! not sure yet, gotta try it out later. that PATH variable must ONLY be related to the node.js path and nothing else

Comment: not sure at all what that means? PATH is a colon-delimited list of directories, the way you add to it is usually by tacking on a dir at the front: `PATH = /path/to/node.js/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @JaredSmith ok, thanks. I'll post the results here as soon as I try it. Though the question here is how to tell npm that one or another folder is the current working folder of node.js and also tell it where to install the global modules.

Comment: You don't get to tell it where to install global modules. What you seem to be asking for is how to use node.js **without** installing it globally on your system, which is a more complex topic than just modifying PATH. Easiest way would be to use a virtualization solution like vagrant or docker.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention how you would like to manage the versions, I will illustrate a simple method using symlinks.  There are packages that can manage the versions for you, such as the [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) if you would rather use those.

Starting with a `node` directory in my user's home, I have populated it with two versions of `node`:

```
$ tree -L 3 node
node
|-- node-v12.16.1-linux-x64
|   |-- CHANGELOG.md
|   |-- LICENSE
|   |-- README.md
|   |-- bin
|   |   |-- node
|   |   |-- npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
|   |   `-- npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
|   |-- include
|   |   `-- node
|   |-- lib
|   |   `-- node_modules
|   `-- share
|       |-- doc
|       |-- man
|       `-- systemtap
`-- node-v13.10.1-linux-x64
    |-- CHANGELOG.md
    |-- LICENSE
    |-- README.md
    |-- bin
    |   |-- node
    |   |-- npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    |   `-- npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
    |-- include
    |   `-- node
    |-- lib
    |   `-- node_modules
    `-- share
        |-- doc
        |-- man
        `-- systemtap
```

You would then make a symbolic link to the version you would like to use:

```
$ ln -s node-v12.16.1-linux-x64 node/nodejs
```

and finally, we need to link all up this through your PATH:

```
$ export PATH=~/node/nodejs/bin:$PATH
```

Now, you should be able to run `node` commands:

```
$ node --version
v12.16.1
$ npm --version
6.13.4
```

You can switch the versions by changing the symbolic link:

```
$ unlink node/nodejs
$ ln -s node-v13.10.1-linux-x64 node/nodejs
$ node --version
v13.10.1
$ npm --version
6.13.7
```

Unfortunately, this does not handle global packages, as all versions would install/use global packages from the same place.  If you have two users attempting to use different versions of `node`, having global packages can break things.

Comment: Thank you! I've just tried it and `export PATH=~/pr/node.js/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/bin:$PATH` and `bash: npm: command not found` shows up on `npm --version`
How will it know which node/npm version to use if I add a number of them to the PATH ?

Comment: I downloaded the linked `tar.gz` in your original question and it had `npm` available.  Did you make sure to extract the contents into the correct directory?  What is the output of `ls -l ~/pr/node.js/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/{bin,lib/node_modules}`?  You will not be able to have multiple versions with the same name, you would just get the first match from `$PATH`.