# Make Python3 script callable from everywhere without making it an executable

Tags: python, path, executable, chmod

I've got a folder: **/root/Desktop/commands/**
This folder contains many Python scripts that should be callable from anywhere from the terminal. How can I make it, that I say once, that all scripts in this folder should be executable (without the "python" prefix of course)?

All I know is, that you have to put the file with a shebang and without the file-ending into /usr/bin/ and make it executable (chmod +x FILENAME)

*In Windows, for example, you can easily put the path (f.e. c:/User/Desktop/commands/) into the environment variables (-> "PATH"). Then you can add the file extension (-> "PATHEXT") and from now on, the file (f.e. myscript.py) is callable from everywhere trough the terminal, even without the "python" prefix and the ".py" ending.*

Thanks for every answer,
(and yeah: stay healthy :))

Comment: you can do the same as in Windows on Unix-Systems: take a look at this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: But when I do this, following error message comes, when typing the command
`bash: /my/path/mycommand: Permission denied`

Comment: Did you run `chmod +x` on those files?

Comment: You need to include this line on the beginning of all files `#!/usr/bin/env python` and set these files executable with `chmod +x filename`. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304896/7211502).