# How to define PATH? Without PATH errors

Tags: bash, command-line, path

When I write in .bashrc:

```
export PATH=\$PATH:\/usr/local/qc/OPENMPI_3_1_4/bin/
```

after a reboot, I get this error with any command line:

```
david@doc1:~> less
If 'less' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
cnf less
```

It only work with the complete path:

```
/usr/bin/less
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Try: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/qc/OPENMPI_3_1_4/bin/`

Comment: @John1024 yes, it worked! Consider to put your complete answer with a briefly explanation

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/117549 ?

Comment: @Another.Chemist  Very good.  As for an answer, it looks like White Owl has already written a good one for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to escape the dollar character

```
export PATH=\$PATH:\/usr/local/qc/OPENMPI_3_1_4/bin/
```

This means you are creating a new `PATH` with a text `$PATH:/usr/local/qc/OPENMPI_3_1_4/bin/`. The existing PATH is lost at that moment.
What you need is

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/qc/OPENMPI_3_1_4/bin/
```

In this case, the old value of PATH (something like `/bin:/usr/bin`) is replacing the $PATH and result would be `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/qc/OPENMPI_3_1_4/bin/`

You will (or can) write `PATH=abc\$def` if the dollar sign is part of the directory name. Which is extremely rare and almost never happen, since the `$` character is used to mark substitutions, and you would have to escape it to reference such directory.

Comment: Safer to quote the whole part after the =, in case some of the additions contain whitespace, or are subsequently edited to do so.