# Launch AppImages with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, appimage

I have the password manager KeePassXC as an AppImage on my system. I run it *thousands* times a day and I want to add a key-bind/shortcut to launch it, not just have the icon on the menu with a regular `.desktop` file.

Edit. I did this:

1. **Create a script** named `keepassxc` (or the name of the AppImage you want to launch) that points to the /path/of/app.AppImage.

   I created mine in a hidden folder called `.bin` in my user's home directory (`~/.bin`) with a content like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /home/username/AppImages/KeePassXC.AppImage
   ```
2. **Add the directory of the script to your `$PATH`**. (In my case the directory was `~/.bin`, so):

   1. Edit the file `~/.profile` (with nano, vim, or any text editor)
   2. Add:

      ```
      export PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"
      ```
   3. Refresh it (or logout - login):

      ```
      source ~/.profile
      ```
3. Edit keyboard shortcuts (this deppends your desktop environment...)

   - The shortcut should have `keepassxc` (or the name you gave to the script) as the **command**
   - Then, select the key combination you want.

Don't forget, of course, to have the **AppImage with permission to be executed**. Cheers!

Edit 2 reason: make notes more clear as requested

Comment: This needs more detail, e.g. show how to add the directory, to the PATH, show how to create a shortcut.

Comment: How to create keyboard shortcuts really depends on your desktop environment/window manager, so I can't really write that here. As for how to add a directory to your $PATH in Linux there are multiple [articles](https://www.howtogeek.com/658904/how-to-add-a-directory-to-your-path-in-linux/)/[questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) already answered about it.