# Manjaro: in which directory should user software go?

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, environment-variables, manjaro

I have a few programs (python, bash, etc., some are my own, some are third-party) that I want to be able to use anywhere. Hence, i thought about putting them somewhere in my $PATH. I recently switched from Ubuntu, [where it is somewhat standard practice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195652/is-there-a-standard-place-for-placing-custom-linux-scripts#195667) to put these things in `/usr/local/bin`. However, now on Manjaro, I get an error message that says `Permission denied`. As I understand, the problem is that on Arch-based OS, the directory `/usr/local/bin` is also used by the package manager, pacman (I read this somewhere but can't find the source anymore).

In summary, what I need is:

- a directory on my $PATH where I can save all these scripts
- the possibilty to have version control in that directory

I am aware that I could just make some directory somewhere on my hard drive and add that to my $PATH, but I'm wondering if there is a common practice in place.

EDIT: This is my $PATH variable:

```
/home/douglas/bin:/home/douglas/bin:/home/douglas/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
```

Does someone know why `/home/douglas/bin` appears twice?

Comment: There is no standard but `~/bin` and `~/.local/bin` are common. You shouldn’t ask two questions but that some directories appear twice means that the file which exports `PATH` got sourced twice. Consider putting environment variables in `.profile` not `.bashrc`. See also [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047).

Answer (score 1):

> The `/usr/local` hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when
> installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being
> overwritten when the system software is updated. It may be used for
> programs and data that are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not
> found in /usr.

https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html#purpose24

If you want to have scripts available for all users on the system put it there.
`pacman` will not overwrite existing files and exits the installation on conflicts.

This is the main question: Do you want scripts/programs available for one specific user only, or for all users on the system?

A proper systemwide implementation for all users and for software with version control (each having a .git or .svn directory) could be put in `/opt/<packagename>`. (If you install java, you may find `/etc/profile.d/jre.sh`)

The shell environment would be extended with a file in  `/etc/profile.d/<packagename>.sh` which is executed by `/etc/profile` whenever a  login shell is started. `<packagename>.sh` would contain environment data like  `PATH=${PATH}:/opt/<packagename>/bin/`

For a single user only put the path of the clone in `~/.profile` and clone it where ever you want it to be in your `/home/<username>` directory.