# Debian 10: Setting PATH variable inside .profile does not work

Tags: bash, debian, path, profile

I'm currently running Debian 10 Xfce and I would like to update my PATH variable to include `/opt/bin` and `~/.local/bin`. As per these - [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059) [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/60221) answers, I put the following lines in my `~/.profile` file:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
        PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
 
if [ -d "/opt/bin" ] ; then
        PATH="/opt/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Now, when I source `.profile` from terminal, everything works well and the `PATH` is updated. As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/566401) answer, `.profile` is source at login, even with a GUI login. So, I expect the `PATH` variable to contain my modified locations when I login. Unfortunately, it does not.
Why isn't profile sourced at login?
How do I properly update my `PATH` to include the locations I want, if putting them inside `.profile` is not gonna work?

Comment: Whether your `.profile` is source on graphical login depends on your login manager. If I remember correctly, GDM and LDM do this, which one are you using? How do you log into your system?

Comment: @terdon I use lightdm login manager.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the debian official documentation :

> Graphical logins do not read a shell's startup files (/etc/profile and
> ~/.profile and so on) by default, but you as a user may choose to
> create a ~/.xsessionrc file which does this.

https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: So, can I create an`~/.xsessionrc` and source my `~/.profile` within it?

Comment: yes, take a look at the link i posted.

Comment: Here's another Debian [Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Xsession) which says `If you choose to dot in one of your regular shell dot files, make sure it does not use bash specific features, zsh specific features, ksh specific features, etc.` How do I know if the `.profile` file contains bash specific features?

Comment: take a look at your `~/.profile` and you'll see

Comment: @RogUE there's no easy answer, I'm afraid. You need to know what features are shell-specific. One thing you should do is make sure you never use `[[ ]]` and always use `[ ]` instead.

Comment: @terdon There's not a lot of commands in my `~/.profile`, just some `if` conditions, one of them sources `/etc/bash_completion`, another one sources `~/.bashrc`, others set the `PATH` variable.

Comment: @RogUE as long as your default shell is bash, then it's fine. If you switch to another shell, you should remove the mention of `/etc/bash_completion` and `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @terdon i don't think so, `~/.profile` sources the bash files only if you use bash as default shell.

Comment: @terdon So, is there a proper method to do it?

Comment: @RogUE what's wrong with the method suggested by the official documentation ?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader no, there's no magic system. If you are sourcing `.profile` from `szh` for example, and have those lines, then `zsh` will attempt to read `.bashrc`. `.profile` is just a shell script, it will do whatever you tell it to do.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader It might be my OCD, but this line in the official documentation caught my eyes: *This is a quicky and dirty approach! Not for the pedantic user*.

Comment: @terdon i'm using a debian 10 and my `~/.profile` says `# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
` so it is checking if the default shell is using bash if not it' doesn't source bash files

Comment: @D'ArcyNader exactly: your profile is explicitly checking. But this is a Debian thing not a general one. You can't assume all profiles will be checking and most do not include that atrocity (OK, in my opinion) which makes your login shells behave like non login shells.

Comment: @terdon the question is about Debian 10 as it clearly says.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader sure, but my point was there is no magic system: `.profile` will do whatever you tell it to do. So if you, or your system, tell it to source `.bashrc` only if running bash, then that's what it will do. But if you don't explicitly tell it to check if you're running bash, then it won't. `.profile` is a file that is very, very commonly modified by users so you cannot assume it is the same as yours just because you run the same OS. I've had the same `.bashrc` and `.profile` files with few modifications for almost 20 years and more than 5 distros.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME Terminal has an option to run the command as a login shell.

[image]

Other graphical consoles will at least let you explicitly configure the command to execute -- this can be `bash --login`. I found this the least painful way to get the behavior I (perhaps naively?) expected.