# btfs init: Find metadata failed: No such file or directory

Tags: bittorrent

I'm currently experienting with btfs. Compiled successfully on a Mac Mini m1.
Then, while applying instructions to setup a demo node as described in

https://docs.btfs.io/docs/btfs-demo, It fails with:

```
shintakou:~ kalou$ btfs init Find metadata failed: No such file or directory

shintakou:~ kalou$  btfs -v btfs version: 2.24 libtorrent version:
1.2.10.0 FUSE library version: 2.9.9 fuse: no mount point
```

Do you know what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Was trying to install BTFS on Digital Ocean droplet with Ubuntu server.
After installation trying to run:

> btfs init

Was getting this output:

> Find metadata failed: No such file or directory

After adding the path correctly following this question:

[How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/493273)

**Got it working**

> Generating TRON key with BIP39 seed phrase...

Now finishing the setup and [Allspot project](https://allspot.store) will have its own BTFS node running!

Comment: Adding what path, specifically?