# Why does cat command only read from stdin?

Tags: cat, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to figure out why my `cat` command refuses to acknowledge the file I provide.

I know that `cat` ignores filenames when they are absent or a `-` is provided, but I am not doing either of those things. The command used to work, but now it won't.

I am using a WSL Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10. I have a simple text file called `hello.txt`. I am testing with the command `cat hello.txt`. I am in the proper directory as well. However, `cat` hangs and waits for me to type something into the terminal, which it then outputs.

If I run `type -a cat` I get this output

```
cat is /home/awallace110/.cargo/bin/cat
cat is /usr/bin/cat
cat is /bin/cat
```

What is going on?

Comment: Hello @steeldriver I get `cat is /home/awallace110/.cargo/bin/cat
cat is /usr/bin/cat
cat is /bin/cat`

Comment: Looks like you have bad kitty in your path.  You should probably move `/home/awallace110/.cargo/bin` behind `/bin`

Comment: Is that https://crates.io/crates/cat by chance?

Comment: @jesse_b I'm fairly new to linux commands and am having trouble moving `/home/awallace110/.cargo/bin` behind `/bin`. Also, I don't think it's the crates version, I never added that to my rust Cargo.toml file.

Comment: Well if you want to confirm that is the issue try `/usr/bin/cat hello.txt` and if that works but `/home/awallace110/.cargo/bin/cat hello.txt` does not work you know that version of cat is no good.  You can either remove that version of cat or find what is setting your path (likely in .profile or .bash_profile) and modify it there.  [How to correctly add to path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path/26059#26059)

Comment: @jesse_b `/usr/bin/cat hello.txt` gave me the proper response. I deleted and re-added the cat file in my `/home/awallace110/.cargo/bin` directory. When running cat in the terminal, it works as normal now, but I have to authenticate as root, which isn't a huge problem. I guess my PATH variable was telling cat to look into the wrong directory that had a faulty version of cat. Not sure why deleting and re-adding it fixed the issue, but it did. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you adding cat to that directory anyway?  Also it sounds like you added it with sudo so your user doesn't have execute permissions