# Path in script different than actual path

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, path

When I `echo $PATH` in a terminal window, it outputs:

```
/home/charles/anaconda3/bin:
/home/charles/anaconda3/condabin:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:
/home/charles/.emacs.d/bin
```

But when I run the script (not as root):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $PATH
```

it only outputs the root paths, not the ones from my home directory:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

I'm trying to launch `spyder` from a script, which comes from:

```
$ which spyder
/home/charles/anaconda3/bin/spyder
```

Is there some way to make the script recognize the parts of the path from my home directory?

**Solved**: I moved the code adding `emacs` and `anaconda` to the path from `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile`.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/237982.  Specifically Gilles answer that talks about how to correct set your PATH variable.  Sounds like you may be setting it in your rc file instead of your profile file.

Comment: In which file do you add the directories `/home/charles/...` to your `PATH`? What is the first line of your script? (= Is the script run by `bash` or by `sh`?) Please [edit] your question to provide this information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome, can we assume that you are not running the script as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script runs in a subshell - meaning that it was spawned by your interactive/login shell. A subshell is a shell spawned for the express purpose of running your script/program. One of the rules for a subshell is that it can access the global variables set by the *"parent shell"*, but **not** the local variables.

This suggests that the `/home/...` variables are *local* variables, meaning that you set them somewhere/somehow - maybe in `~/.bashrc`?

The solution is that you must declare your local PATH variables inside your script. You could do this as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/charles/anaconda3/bin:/home/charles/anaconda3/condabin:/home/charles/.emacs.d/bin"
```

This PATH is now *local* to your script/subshell, and will not be propagated as a global variable.

Comment: Redoing your PATH in every individual script would get annoying fast. Far better to set the PATH somewhere like `.bash_profile` that will be sourced by the login shell and use `export` so it gets passed on to all forked shells (or there may be other options depending on login manager, init system or choice of shell).

Comment: @frabjous: Good point. I didn't put that in my answer as the OP asked about a specific script, not all scripts. Sometimes, a de-scoped PATH is a *good thing*.  :)